# Contentful GraphQL filter with relational queries and reference fields

Tags: graphql, contentful

I'm currently trying to filter entries with a field `references, many`.
In other words, the field takes multiple locations with each locations consisting of `city` among other fields.

For my query I want to get every entry that has a location with a specific city name set.

The following query filters an entry that takes only on reference for location, how would it look like when having many?

```
export const NEWS_ARTICLES = gql`
    query GetNewsArticles($location: String) {
        entryCollection(
            where: {
                location: { city: $location }
            }
        ) {
            items {
                location
            }
        }
    }
`;
```

Pulling GraphQL's schema all I get is  `locationCollection_exists` - is this even possible?

I found the following article, which seems to do what I desire, but for the Filter API and not GraphQL: https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/concepts/relational-queries/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Contentful DevRel here.

Filtering by a linked collection entry is not supported right now. What you can do though it flip the query around.

```
export const NEWS_ARTICLES = gql`
    query GetNewsArticles($location: String) {
        cityCollection(
             # your filter
        ) {
            items {
                linkedFrom {
                    # all the entries linking to this entry
                }
            }
        }
    }
`;
```

You can find more information about this approach [in the docs](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/graphql/#links-to-a-specific-item) or [this blogpost](https://www.contentful.com/blog/2021/06/15/filter-entries-by-linked-references-in-graphql-api/).

Comment: Thanks! I have one more field that takes `reference, many`, namely `mainTags`, same behavior like `locations` - what's the best practice as of right now in this case? Another `mainTagsCollection` with linked from inside of the same query?

Comment: Additionally I have to filter the `linkedFrom` entries by another singular field `category`, but there's now `where` available within `linkedFrom`

Comment: Unfortunately, for nested collection filters, I think you have to multiply the queries and assemble the result in the client in that case.

Comment: Is filtering by a linked collection entry a feature that might be introduced sometime in the future for the GraphQL API or rather not? I mean it has been already for all the REST APIs and SDKs, hasn't it?

Comment: And sorry for bothering you here again, but when I have a singular reference field with multiple possible content types, am I able to somehow filter the parent entry for the singular reference's content type or same story like `multi`?

Comment: Might be introduced but I can't give a timelines. I'm not sure I understand the 2nd question. A bunch of people hang out in slack, if you want to join. contentful.com/slack